# How to find the median key of a B-tree with max degree even?

Tags: b-tree

I need help to find the median key to split in a B tree.
I have this tree with max degree 6 (m = 3, max 5 keys and 6 pointers to child):

```
(5,6,7,8,9)
```

Then, I need to insert 10, splitting the tree. But I don't know which number will be promoted to parent. I found many answers to that, first one said that number 7 would be promoted, the other one was that you can choose between 7 and 8. Which one should I follow?

Promoting 7:

```
      (7)
     /   \
  (5,6)  (8,9,10)
```

Promoting 8:

```
      (8)
     /   \
 (5,6,7)  (9,10)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Why not promoot `9` ? And have `5,6,7,8` on the left side, and `10` on the right side? It might be that changes are higher that next value to be inserted is `11` (or higher).

Comment: You cannot have less than 2 keys in a node, with m = 3:
Max degree: 2*m-1 | 
Minimum: m-1

Comment: I found the solution, you always split by the middle number before insert another one, so it will always stay odd and you can divide it.